# Struts 2.3 Upgrading OGNL Issue

Tags: struts2

I have a website which was originally built using Struts 2.0. I am now upgrading it to Struts 2.3. This website has include files that perform an AJAX request (searching for inventory based on a common search form). The AJAX request submits the entire form to the searchInventory action. This worked fine in Struts 2.0, but in 2.3 I get exceptions in the error log which look like this:

```
[STDOUT] WARN [com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack] - CommonsLogger.warn(60) | Error setting expression 'nonInventoryRelatedField' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@833d35'
ognl.OgnlException: target is null for setProperty(null, "9", [Ljava.lang.String;@833d35)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:2309)
    at ognl.ASTProperty.setValueBody(ASTProperty.java:127)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateSetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:220)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.setValue(SimpleNode.java:301)
    at ognl.ASTChain.setValueBody(ASTChain.java:227)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateSetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:220)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.setValue(SimpleNode.java:301)
    at ognl.Ognl.setValue(Ognl.java:737)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.setValue(OgnlUtil.java:217)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.trySetValue(OgnlValueStack.java:186)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:173)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setParameter(OgnlValueStack.java:151)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.setParameters(ParametersInterceptor.java:292)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:203)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:192)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.LoggingInterceptor.intercept(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.TimerInterceptor.intercept(TimerInterceptor.java:120)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:511)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:399)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SessionFixationProtectionFilter.doFilterHttp(SessionFixationProtectionFilter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    at org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:278)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

The problem is that the page including the inventory search has several other fields which are not related to the inventory search (and do not have a getter/settter in the inventorySearch action). Under Struts 2.0, these extra fields are ignored by the inventorySearch action. However, Struts 2.3 throws the above exception when these extra fields are posted with the form. Does anyone have any good ideas about how to best resolve this issue?

I have already thought of the following options:

1. Find all pages which include the inventory search and all extra fields from each of these pages. Then take all of these extra fields and add a getter/setter for them in the inventory search action.
2. Try to redesign the inventory search AJAX to not submit the form, but instead use a DOM manipulation to retrieve all of the inventory related fields and omit the other fields.
3. Change my logging settings to suppress OgnlExceptions.

Are there any other good ideas or arguments for/against the above choices?

Thanks

Comment: +1 In the past I've done #3, but I would be interested in knowing what others suggest. The first two options are far too invasive.

Comment: This is a long and ever going discussion in mailing list for the same set of warnings being thrown by OGNL and most of them favor to adjust log level to suppress warnings.

Comment: Yep, I ran into this as well and went with changing the logging for production but leaving it for dev.  It really is harmless.

Comment: Can please someone direct me to where I can suppress the OGNL exceptions? Btw. *they are written to STDOUT* which makes it a little hard to suppress when you don't want to build OGNL yourself. Any helpers?

Comment: Serious? Suppressing the warnings is the best we an do? Isn't there some way to filter out the params the action doesn't care about (i.e. ParameterNameAware maybe)?

Answer (score 0):

We also had the same thing here. It is an exception, but the logging level is set to warning.

It is kind of annoying to have that long exceptions when actually the system wants to warn you.

What Struts 2.3.x wants is to raise more awareness of the things.

You may opt to raise the level of logging to ERROR so that the warning doesn't always appear and bloating your production log files. At least that's what we did.

For example if you are using log4j.xml, you can add this:

```
<logger name="com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack" additivity="false">
    <level value="ERROR" />
<appender-ref ref="LOGFILE" />
</logger>
```

Later in your development environment, you can still enable that logging and incrementally work to match the missing properties in your action classes with your OGNL value stack usage.